# Writing to a "application/octet-stream" file on linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, permission-denied

I am working on application which should block some USB devices.

I have found a way how could be blocking done. Problem is, as it's written [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/authorization.txt), that I need to write some string into `/sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe` file. Mentioned file is `application/octet-stream` and I can't find a way how to read or write to this file.

I have tried `vim`, `echo`, `hexdump` with sudo or as root, but every time I get *"Permission denied"* or *"No such device"* message. I did not tried it in C/C++, which is my app using, but I guess it would bring same result.

Can anyone help me understand how kernel developers meant writing to that file?

Comment: It's meaningless to say that a filename has a MIME-type - that's a description of the *content*, and not something a filesystem has any knowledge of.  The device files under `/sys` are generally accessed as plain text, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get "Permission denied", it means you are not opening the file with root privileges:

```
$ sudo echo 4-1 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe
bash: /sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe: Permission denied

$ echo 4-1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe > /dev/null
(no error)
```

If you get "No such device", it means you are writing the wrong string:

```
$ echo 'foobar' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe > /dev/null
tee: /sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe: No such device

$ echo '3-1.3.1:1.3' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers_probe > /dev/null
(no error)
```

Comment: More specifically, *with appropriate privileges* - don't use root where a lesser user will do!  (Admittedly, in this particular case, the filesystem entry is normally `--w------- root:root`, so root is the only permitted user this time.)

Comment: Thank you, I have found that solution with _tee_ tool but when I got _"no such device"_ message, for some reasons, I still thought that it was problem with privileges. Only problem was me, writing interface wrong.